# How to write validations for Input tag in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React project In my project I have to write validations for Input tag.
My goal is I have an Input tag, that Input tag type is number, Now I have to write validations like this
in that Input tag it has to take only six digits. And I cannot put like this -100000. it only has to take only digits no other  symbols.

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-4'>
          <form>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label for="pincode">Pincode</label>
              <input type="number" className="form-control" id="pin" placeholder="Enter Pincode"></input>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-5">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you have any questions please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think that You can use React-useRef hook. For example

```
const [input, setInput] = useState([])
const number = useRef()


const handleSubmit = (event) => {
   //i said to react, i will do it myself 
   event.preventDefault();

   const pincode = number.current.value
    
   const data = {
     pincode: pincode
   }

   if(data.pincode){
     setInput([...input, data])
     number.current.value = 0
   }else{ console.log("oops")}
}

return (
   <div className="container">
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-4'>
          <form onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label for="pincode">Pincode</label>
              <input ref = {number} type="number" className="form-control" id="pin" placeholder="Enter Pincode"></input>
            </div>
            <button  onClick = {handleSubmit}type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-5">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
)
```